# Low-resolution Images on loading screens?

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues

I don't know why, but it seems every image in the game is in very low resolution.

[image]
[image]

Even tho my options are

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm assuming you aren't playing the game with it partially downloaded?

Comment: Nope. CD Installed. And fully downloaded a few days ago.

Comment: Strange; I replicated your graphics settings as shown in your screenshot, but I didn't encounter the issue.

Comment: Did you try playing Diablo without the FPS and voice chat(?) overlays - it's a wild guess but maybe they're interfering with something. (Yes, that means I can't replicate your problems as well).

Comment: Those are XFire, and extern overlay for voicechat and FPS. http://www.xfire.com/. But now I wonder if I go and delete the images folder, will diablo 3 redownload them correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue before. I'm using a ATI 5700 series. I fixed it by opening Catalyst Control Center, clicking on preferences, and then clicking on "restore to factory settings." Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Yesterday's update fixed that. Thanks.